# PHP Http Requests & Pecl/Pear on Hosting Servers

Tags: php, pear, pecl, http-request

I am new to PHP and web development. I am trying to build a basic Facebook application. Hence it is necessary to use Http Requests to get user data from Graph API within Facebook. I checked how to make requests with PHP yet I saw that Http request methods are not built-in. I understand that I need to install appropriate libraries to use them and everything was fine until I got that it is almost impossible to install Pecl or Pear to a hosting service(i am using Godaddy).

I have looked into lots of sites including Stackoverflow yet there are no answers. Plenty of sites explain how to install packages to a local server.

I could only tried [Pear | go-pear.phar](http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar) web installation yet it did not work. I do not know how to execute a .phar file even though I checked the documentation([Pear Installation Doc](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php)). This link, [Installing Pear on Godaddy Hosting](http://abbyandwin.net/blog/2008/06/16/installing-pear-on-godaddy-shared-accounts/), explains what I have tried to do.

One more question, if it is not possible to install any of these packages, so how to I make HTTP Requests with PHP? Is there any other way?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php can do http requests, if allow_url_fopen is enabled. And there's always the CURL library (if enabled). You can test both with something as simple as:

```
$c = curl_init();
$txt = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

If curl's not installed, the first line fails. If url operations are disabled, then the second line will fail.

Comment: I have just tried it seems working. However, just curiosity, why i need $c = curl_init() ? How do I use it for example? And will this allow me to make access token requests on Facebook?

Comment: @msh just look at curl_init() documentation

Comment: Also is it possible to use file_get_contents() without initializing Curl?

Comment: yes, php's internal streams/url operations are independent of curl. And yes, it could do a token request, since it's just doing plain-jane HTTP operations.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more thing, why then only packages explained on the PHP manual site and is it really impossible to install Pear/Pecl to a hosting without controlling it? Sorry if these seem ankward I just could not find an appropriate answer anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: if it's a shared server, they're not going to let you install stuff into the server, since that could affect OTHER users of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hosting you are using with Go Daddy is the Linux 4GH hosting, PEAR and Pecl should already be installed and available for use.